# Can't see latest submission in Windows App Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have submitted an new version of windows app to microsoft app store. Windows store dashboard submission is saying new version of app is in the store. But when i try to look up my app in windows store i get a old version like one year old version. I looked it up using browser incognito mode to see whether everyone seeing the same thing and it does show the same thing.

It was working few months before. Not sure why its showing release date as a old date. Please help

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure why its showing release date as a old date.

The **Release date** in the Microsoft Store represents the *release date of the app in the Store not the update date of the app*.Once the first publishing has begun, you can no longer cancel the submission or change its release date.After your app has been published and has become available in the Store, you will no longer be able to select a Release date (since the app will already have been released).More details you could refer to [Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/configure-precise-release-scheduling#release) and [Publishing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/the-app-certification-process#publishing).

Comment: But how do i know which version is served from windows store?

Comment: You could fill the update information in the [What's new in this version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-app-store-listings#whats-new-in-this-version) on the **Store listing** page.For an update to an existing app, this is where you can let customers know what's changed in the latest release.